# Saving Instance State

Tags: java, android

This is my activity:

```
package com.workspace.pockethero;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class PocketHero extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final String TAG = PocketHero.class.getSimpleName();
    static int centreX;
    static int centreY;
    static int bottomA;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//fullscreen
        setRequestedOrientation(
        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);//landscape mode
        getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);//keep screen on
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//no title

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        centreX = display.getWidth()/2;
        centreY = display.getHeight()/2;
        bottomA = display.getHeight();
        // requesting to turn the title OFF
        // making it full screen
        // set our MainGamePanel as the View
        setContentView(new MainGamePanel(this));
        Log.d(TAG, "View added");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {  
        //replaces the default 'Back' button action  
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)  
        {
        }
        return true;  
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Destroying...");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping...");
        super.onStop();
    }

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
}
```

This activity is a real mess. I want my activity to save itself when minimized the game, and restore itself, when i launch it again. What should i add or remove in this activity? I'm new at android developing, so i don't know what else is needed in this activity...

Answer (score 1):

If you want your game state saved between executions of the app, then you don't want to be looking at saving instance state. Instead, you want to save your data in some form of persistent storage. On app start-up (in `onCreate`) you would read the persistent data (or initialize default data if none was found--as on the first execution). Options for saving data are described in the guide topic [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use serialization. Wrap your data (centreX...) in a Serializable class, save it in onDestroy() and load it in onStart().

Here are 2 convenience methods I use all day long:

```
public static Object load(String fname , Context cont)
{
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = cont.openFileInput(fname);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object loadedObject = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
        return loadedObject;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Father.print("[IO.load]Load "+fname+" failed: "+ e.getMessage() );
        return null;
    }
}

public static boolean save(String fname , Object o , Context cont)
{
    try
    {
        if(o == null) Father.print("WARNING: saving null");
        FileOutputStream fos = cont.openFileOutput(fname , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(o);
        oos.close();
        fos.close(); 
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Father.printe("[IO.save]Error saving object: ", e );
        return false;
    }
}
```